# Doctrine 2: Generated entities from database don't have namespaces

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I am creating entities from the database trough the `\Doctrine\ORM\Tools\DisconnectedClassMetadataFactory()` class. This works perfectly! Except for the namespace generation. There are no namespaces generated. I am storing my entities in `App/Model/Entities`.

### Does anyone know how to make the generator add namespaces to the entities?

This is the code I use to generate the entities:

```
<?php
$em->getConfiguration()->setMetadataDriverImpl(
    new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\DatabaseDriver(
        $em->getConnection()->getSchemaManager()
    )
);

$cmf = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\DisconnectedClassMetadataFactory();
$cmf->setEntityManager($em);
$metadata = $cmf->getAllMetadata();

// GENERATE PHP ENTITIES!
$entityGenerator = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\EntityGenerator(); 
$entityGenerator->setGenerateAnnotations(true); 
$entityGenerator->setGenerateStubMethods(true); 
$entityGenerator->setRegenerateEntityIfExists(false); 
$entityGenerator->setUpdateEntityIfExists(true); 
$entityGenerator->generate($metadata, __dir__. '/Model/Entities");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can set the namespace when importing from the database, because the EntityGenerator takes the namespace information from the metadata. The database does not have or need namespaces, so the information does not automatically come from there.

You could try looping over the $metadata object and adding the namespace yourself to class names. The code in the EntityGenerator that retrieves the namespace is quite simple:

```
private function _getNamespace(ClassMetadataInfo $metadata)
{
    return substr($metadata->name, 0, strrpos($metadata->name, '\\'));
}
```

If all else fails, you can always implement your own EntityGenerator that you can feed a namespace to use. We did that in our large project, where there are some other custom tasks to be done during generation. However, the EntityGenerator is not easily overriden, lots of private methods and properties so you probably have to copy&paste the whole thing.

Comment: Thank you! Your solution with implemention my own entity generator is great! I will go with that one. Better than my temporary solution of making XML mapping files from the database. String replace all the XML files. And then generate entities from that :P thank you again!

Answer (score 9):

I think, the better way is set namespace directly to driver

```
<?php
$driver = new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\DatabaseDriver($em->getConnection()->getSchemaManager());
$driver->setNamespace('App\\Model\\Entities\\');

$em->getConfiguration()->setMetadataDriverImpl($driver);

....
```

Comment: This worked for me and generated the entities with a correct namespace declaration.

Answer (score -3):

You may use this PHP script to generate entities from database tables.
This script adds a sample namespace to generated files, so you can set your Namespace instead.
https://gist.github.com/SamvelG/3b39622844f23cac7e76#file-doctrine-entity-generator-php